# foobar2000 couldn't play a cue file

Tags: flac, foobar2000, cue

I have just installed foobar2000 to play my new album (In a folder there are over 30 flac files, a cue file and other stuff) but it couldn't play the cue file.
However, it can play single or multiple flac files without any issues.

#### error message

```
Unable to open item for playback (Object not found):
"C:\Users\Emrehan\Music\Glenn Gould - Bach - Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version) [flac]\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version).cue" / index: 1

Unable to open item for playback (Object not found):
"C:\Users\Emrehan\Music\Glenn Gould - Bach - Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version) [flac]\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version).cue" / index: 2

Unable to open item for playback (Object not found):
"C:\Users\Emrehan\Music\Glenn Gould - Bach - Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version) [flac]\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version).cue" / index: 3

Unable to open item for playback (Object not found):
"C:\Users\Emrehan\Music\Glenn Gould - Bach - Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version) [flac]\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version).cue" / index: 4
```

#### cue file

```
REM GENRE Classical
REM DATE 1981
REM DISCID D50C0520
REM COMMENT "ExactAudioCopy v0.99pb4"
PERFORMER "Glenn Gould"
TITLE "JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)"
FILE "Glenn Gould\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)\01--Aria.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Aria"
    PERFORMER "Glenn Gould"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "Glenn Gould\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)\02--Variation 1 a 1 
Clav..wav" WAVE
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "Variation 1 a 1 Clav."
    PERFORMER "Glenn Gould"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "Glenn Gould\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)\03--Variation 2 a 1 
Clav..wav" WAVE
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "Variation 2 a 1 Clav."
    PERFORMER "Glenn Gould"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
FILE "Glenn Gould\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)\04--Variation 3 a 1 
Clav. Canone all'Unisono.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "Variation 3 a 1 Clav. Canone all'Unisono"
    PERFORMER "Glenn Gould"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

I see for example this

> FILE "Glenn Gould\JS Bach- Goldberg Variations, BWV988 (1981 Version)\03--Variation 2 a 1 Clav..wav" WAVE

do you see it ends with 2 dots?
try to replace all the ..wav to .wav, it should work.

Comment: i tried but it don't work.

Comment: the main problem here is the name file+extention in the description inside the cue file. It has to match exactly the file name between the cue and the real file you have.I'm thinking, if those are flac files, substitute the .wav with .flac it should work. they have to match, remember that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is index numbers.
Every one 00:00:00

Cue Sample

```
TRACK 06 AUDIO
 TITLE "XY"
    PERFORMER "XY"
    INDEX 00 22:27:37
    INDEX 01 22:29:19
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I received an error message similar to yours.

As already specified in other answers here, the most important thing is the path to the audio file to be correctly specified in the cue sheet.

However, even if the path seems perfectly you can have surprises like the one explained below.

In such cases, **check for non-ASCII characters in the file name**.

This kind of error is very annoying because you can waste a lot of time exploring other ways to fix it.

Therefore, when nothing seems to work, simply rename the audio file and specify the new name, next to the ***FILE*** metadata, in the cue sheet.

You can see below how I identified the non-ASCII character and how I got rid of it.

[image]

This is the cue sheet used in my case:

```
REM GENRE Podcast
REM DATE 2021
PERFORMER "Unknown"
TITLE "Podcаst (1-3)"
FILE "Podcаst (1-3).wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Lecture 1"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "Lecture 2"
    INDEX 01 06:41:10
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "Lecture 3"
    INDEX 01 14:24:32
```